# Changing icon of FirefoxHTML for PDF alone

Tags: firefox, windows-8.1, pdf, icons

Fact that almost all PDF readers takes a little while to start up in my old laptop, I decided to use PDF.js of FF instead, helps me avoid one extra software running as well. Setting it as default was not a worry, but the icon is.

FF treats PDF as FirefoxHTML, hence gives Firefox HTML icon to PDF as well. Anyway to change it to something else more PDF-y instead of HTML?

I tried quite a lot of things, including changing icon of .pdf in Windows, but when .pdf is associated to Firefox, there's provision only to change icon of FirefoxHTML (That includes HTML pages as well, I believe), and not PDF alone. Any way to acheive this?

Comment: This should help. [How to Change the Default Icon for a File Type in Windows?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/change-default-icon-file-type-windows/) Firefox.exe doesn't have a PDF icon.. so you have to download a PDF icon from other source/online

Comment: @w32sh, that doesn't work - because here PDF is opened as "FirefoxHTML" - the same for HTML and other filetypes opned by Firefox. So changing it following this guide will change it not only for PDF, but for every thing else. Must confess this is the temporary solution I use now, putting a common icon for PDF and HTML, something which looks good compared to default firefox icon!

Comment: You can create a custom ProgID for PDF files (such as FirefoxPDF) if required, and assign an icon to it.

Comment: And this should help. [Change PDF File icon with Firefox as the default viewer](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/set-custom-icon-pdf-files-firefox-default-pdf-viewer/)

Answer (score 1):

After following every guide on the net and doing my tests I've found this solution (for windows 10 but you can try it). Download [Default Program Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/), choose "File Types Settings" and then on the bottom "Change an extension's file type". Select pdf and choose "Add a new file type". Add a quick description (like "PDF file format") and choose your icon. Finally press "Save file Type", or click the little arrow on its side and choose Save to .reg file to see what's gonna change in your registry (remember to use it if you do this). 
This is what used for me changing the .nfo file icon:

```
; Create File Type
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\classes\nfo_auto_file]
@="Nfo"
"FriendlyTypeName"="Nfo"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\classes\nfo_auto_file\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Users\\User\\Pictures\\icon\\ico\\nfo.ico,0"

; Change Extension's File Type
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.nfo]
@="nfo_auto_file"
```

It's going to create a new class with your icon and associate the pdf extension with it. At this point It COULD work already (refresh windows icons before going on). I don't know why it still didn't work for me (it wasn't associating the class correctly), so I had to download [Types](http://ystr.github.io/apps/types/) and do it manually. Start it, find PDF and double click on it. Check "classes" if it isn't already and choose the previously created class (DPE should have named it pdf_auto_file). At this point it should work. I guess I could track the changes made by Types and create a .reg file working without these 2 software but... not today ;D

Comment: [And here's a gif I made for you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjgSr.gif)